# Now I have all three red, green and yellow pawns and I just have to find one blue one

Tags: word-usage

I was playing "Snakes and Ladders" with my cousin. My brother came and scattered all the pawns. After looking for the pawns for a while I could find the red, green,  yellow pawns and three blue pawns. (One blue pawn was missing.)

> I've found **all** the red, yellow and green ones, now I just need to find one blue one.

Does "all" sound natural here?

Thank you:)

Comment: I don't think you mean *pawns*. I think you mean *pieces*. In terms of games, I've only knows chess to have pawns.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would sound better to a native English speaker if you said

> I've found **all of the** red, yellow and green ones, now I just need to find one **more** blue one.

or possibly just

> I've found them all except for a blue one.

Comment: The second one does not seem right. There are three complete colours, with four pawns each.

Comment: @WeatherVane you are right, I misread the OP. I'll edit my answer an hope it meets with your approval!

Comment: Yes, and obviously I meant "the first one".